# code example for bytecode inspection using asm

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Assume a java class without source code available, we just have the .class file. The class implements JDK's `Comparable` interface. I want to know programmatically which fields/getters 
the `compareTo` method accesses.

Using `asm` bytecode library I want to get a list of all getters or field accesses called within a certain method. Are there any code examples available?

Comment: This will require some level of dataflow analysis, in addition to simply determining which fields are accessed. I would probably start by looking at the [FindBugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452785/code-example-for-bytecode-inspection-using-asm) source.

Comment: I'd hope that ASM's documentation includes some examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ASM, you would have to use a custom `MethodVisior` which will be called for each method invocation within a method's byte code. You would have to create this visitor from a custom `ClassVisitor` that only returns this method visitor for the `compareTo` method.

```
new ClassReader(Foo.class.getName()).accept(new ClassVisitor() {
  @Override
  public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, 
      String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    if(name.equals("compareTo") { // We found a method named 'compareTo'
      return new MethodVisitor() {
        @Override // Callback for byte code method instructions
        public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, 
            String name, String desc) {
          System.out.println("Method " + name + " was called on " + owner);
        }
        @Override // Callback for byte code field instructions
        public void visitFieldInsn(int opcode, String owner, 
            String name, String desc) {
          System.out.println("Field " + name + " was accessed on " + owner);
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I did not include constructor arguments in the code snippet. If the `compareTo` method might be overloaded, you would have to include further checks on what methods are called. Also, you might need to further inspect the method instruction for its descriptor and owner, two concepts that are thoroughly discussed in the [ASM manual](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf). You can make use of the [`Type`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html) class to simplify your task.

Depending on what you known about the `compareTo` methods, the simpler the logic will be.